# BorderLayout and JPanel with JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, border-layout

I use:

```
BorderLayout a = new BorderLayout();
setLayout(a);
JPanel b = new JPanel();
```

now, if I use:

```
JButton c = new JButton("Press");
b.add(c);
add("East", b);
```

my JButton will appear normally. BUT if I say instead:

```
JLabel c = new JLabel();
c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
c.setOpaque(true);
add("East", b);
```

my black JLabel won't appear, which I want to. Why does this happen? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JLabel c = new JLabel();
```

You have an empty label, so I'm guessing the size if (0, 0) and there is nothing to paint. Try adding some text.

Also the following is incorrect:

```
add("East", b);
```

That is the old way of adding a constraint. Don't use hardcoded values and the constraint is specified second:

```
add(b, BorderLayout.???);
```

Read the BorderLayout API or the Swing tutorial on `Using a Border Layout` for the appropriate constraint.